# How to move object's hitbox/content size with Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I would like to make a button with large hover picture on top of if with Cocos2D MenuItems. I tried to make it with 2 sprites which are larger than the are I want user to be able to touch - a bit like the iPhone keyboard.

I figured I could make the hitbox of the button smaller with `[button setContentSize:CGSizeMake(22, 22)];`, but couldn't find a way to move it. I want the touchable area to be in the middle bottom area.

Other way would be to add an object aboce the button when selected, but I don't know how to do that with Cocos2D's MenuItems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing this....

```
CCMenuItem *MenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"Button.png" selectedImage:@"ButtonSel.png"  target:self selector:@selector(ButtonTapped:)];
  CCMenu *myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:MenuItem, nil];
[self addChild:myMenu];
```

but the ButtonSel is the image when you hover over it

it should work but if it doesn't play around with anchorPoints

i mean there's no reason why the selected button shouldn't be bigger than the non-selected one

i didn't actually try this..so let me know if it works

Comment: Haha. Such a simple way. I did a workaround, but this actually works. The hitbox will be sized based on the normalsprite, not the hover one. Thank you.